# What is tf.extract_image_patches method meant for?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, sliding-window

I want to divide my images into smaller windows which will be send to a neural net for training (e.g. for face detectors training). I found [`tf.extract_image_patches`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/extract_image_patches) method in Tensorflow which seemed like exactly what I need. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731433/understanding-tf-extract-image-patches-for-extracting-patches-from-an-image) explains what it does.

The example there shows input of `(1x10x10x1)` (numbers `1` through `100` in order) given the `ksize` is `(1, 3, 3, 1)` (and `strides` `(1, 5, 5, 1)`). The output is this:

```
 [[[[ 1  2  3 11 12 13 21 22 23]
    [ 6  7  8 16 17 18 26 27 28]]

   [[51 52 53 61 62 63 71 72 73]
    [56 57 58 66 67 68 76 77 78]]]]
```

But I'd expect windows like this (of a shape `(Nx3x3x1)`, so that it's `N` patches/windows of the size `3x3`):

```
[[[1, 2, 3]
  [11, 12, 13]
  [21, 22, 23]]
    ...
```

So why are all patch values stored in 1D? Does it mean that this method is not meant for the purposes I described above and i can't use it to prepare batches for training? I also found another method for patches extracting, [`sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d.html) and this one really does what I was expecting. So should I understand it like that these two methods don't do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, these functions return different tensors (multi-dimensional arrays).

First, [`tf.extract_image_patches`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/extract_image_patches) documentation reads:

> Returns:
>
> A Tensor. Has the same type as images. 4-D Tensor with shape `[batch,
>   out_rows, out_cols, ksize_rows * ksize_cols * depth]` containing image
>   patches with size `ksize_rows x ksize_cols x depth` vectorized in the
>   "depth" dimension. Note `out_rows` and `out_cols` are the dimensions of
>   the output patches.

Basically, this says that `[1, 2, 3]`, `[11, 12, 13]`, `[21, 22, 23]` windows are flattened, or *vectorized in the "depth" dimension*. The `out_rows` and `out_cols` are calculated from the `strides` argument, which in this case is `strides=[1, 5, 5, 1]`, and by `padding`, which is `'VALID'`. As a result, the output shape is `(1, 2, 2, 9)`.

In other words:

- `strides` changes the spatial dimensions
- `ksizes` changes the depth

Note that the output tensor does contain all individual windows, so you can access them through selection.

---

On the other hand, [`sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d.html):

> Returns:
>
> `patches` : array, shape = `(n_patches, patch_height, patch_width)` or `(n_patches, patch_height, patch_width, n_channels)` The
>   collection of patches extracted from the image, where `n_patches` is
>   either `max_patches` or the total number of patches that can be
>   extracted.

This is exactly what you describe: each window takes the whole spatial dimensions `patch_height, patch_width`. Here, the result shape depends on the `patch_size`, striding and padding is *not supported*, and the first dimension is calculated as the total number of patches.

Comment: So what is the tensorflow method for? I imagined that "patch extraction" is exactly what the sklearn method does and I'd use it but I need striding...