# Trying to extract patches from image and getting "UnimplementedError: Only support ksizes across space"

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I was **trying to split my image through 4 patches** when I came through the following error:

`UnimplementedError: Only support ksizes across space`

```py
iterator = tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(parsed_dataset) 
image,label = iterator.get_next()
image_height = image.shape[0]
image_width = image.shape[1]
# Since the expected type is (batch,height,width,channels), i have tryied to expand my image that have
# dimensions: (800,344,3) to (1,800,344,3) but didn't solved the error.
#image = tf.expand_dims(image ,0)
images = list(image)
extracted_patches = tf.image.extract_patches(images=images,
                                             sizes=[1,int(0.25*image_height),int(0.25*image_width),3],
                                             strides=[1,int(0.25*image_height),int(0.25*image_width),3],
                                             rates=[1,1,1,1],
                                             padding="SAME")
```

#### Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-23c2aff4c306> in <module>()
     17                                              strides=[1,int(0.25*image_height),int(0.25*image_width),3],
     18                                              rates=[1,1,1,1],
---> 19                                              padding="SAME")
     20 
     21 

/Users/lucianoaraujo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.pyc in extract_image_patches_v2(images, sizes, strides, rates, padding, name)
   4657   """
   4658   return gen_array_ops.extract_image_patches(images, sizes, strides, rates,
-> 4659                                              padding, name)
   4660 
   4661 

/Users/lucianoaraujo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_array_ops.pyc in extract_image_patches(images, ksizes, strides, rates, padding, name)
   2542       else:
   2543         message = e.message
-> 2544       _six.raise_from(_core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
   2545   # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
   2546   if not isinstance(ksizes, (list, tuple)):

/Users/lucianoaraujo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.pyc in raise_from(value, from_value)
    735 else:
    736     def raise_from(value, from_value):
--> 737         raise value
    738 
    739 

UnimplementedError: Only support ksizes across space. [Op:ExtractImagePatches]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further research I was able to manage by changing from:

```py
images = list(image)
extracted_patches = tf.image.extract_patches(images=images,
                                             sizes=[1,int(0.25*image_height),int(0.25*image_width),3],
                                             strides=[1,int(0.25*image_height),int(0.25*image_width),3],
                                             rates=[1,1,1,1],
                                             padding="SAME")
```

**To :**

```py
image = tf.expand_dims(image ,0)
extracted_patches = tf.image.extract_patches(images=image,
                                             sizes=[1,int(0.25*image_height),int(0.25*image_width),1],
                                             strides=[1,int(0.25*image_height),int(0.25*image_width),1],
                                             rates=[1,1,1,1],
                                             padding="SAME")
```

And then **reshape to obtain 3 channel images:**

```py
patches = tf.reshape(extracted_patches,[-1,int(0.25*image_height),int(0.25*image_width),3])
```