# model.predict doesn't work with Keras Custom Layer (inference error)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I've developed a custom convolutional layer. I can use it inside a model and train it (model.fit works), but model.predict() yields an error!

I will add a simple code to demonstrate how the code is structured.

```
modelx1 = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.Input(shape=(49,)), Dense(1, activation = 'relu')])

class customLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
 def __init__(self,n=10):super(customLayer, self).__init__()
 def call(self, inputs):
  _, Dim0,Dim1, Dim3 = inputs.shape
  input_victorized = tf.image.extract_patches(images=inputs, sizes=[-1, 7, 7, 1],
                          strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],rates=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
  input_victorized2 = tf.reshape(input_victorized, [-1,49])
  model_output = modelx1(input_victorized2)
  out = tf.reshape(model_output,[-1,Dim0,Dim1,Dim3])
  return out
```

The custom layer reshapes the input, then feeds it to 'modelx1' then it reshapes the output.

Here is a simple model where the custom layer is used:

```
input1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(28,28,1))
x =  Conv2D(filters = 2, kernel_size = 5, activation = 'relu')(input1)
Layeri = customLayer()(x)
xxc = Flatten()(Layeri)
y = Dense(units = 3, activation = 'softmax')(xxc)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input1, outputs=y)
model.summary()
```

The error appears when I run model.predict:

```
model.predict(np.ones([100,28,28,1]))

UnimplementedError:  Only support ksizes across space.
     [[node model_58/custom_layer_9/ExtractImagePatches
 (defined at <ipython-input-279-953feb59f882>:7)
]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_14640]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node model_58/custom_layer_9/ExtractImagePatches:
In[0] model_58/conv2d_98/Relu (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py:4867)
```

Comment: Maybe this one helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63177786/trying-to-extract-patches-from-image-and-getting-unimplementederror-only-suppo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:-

```
image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
extracted_patches = tf.image.extract_patches(images = image,
sizes = [1, int(0.5 * image_height), int(0.5 * image_width), 1],
strides = [1, int(0.5 * image_height), int(0.5 * image_width), 1],
rates = [1, 1, 1, 1],
padding = "SAME")
```

And then use `tf.reshape` to extract these patches

```
patches = tf.reshape(extracted_patches, 
[-1,int(0.5*image_height),int(0.5*image_width),3])
```

I had a similar error a couple of months back; This Fixed it!

`